# Locating indices of points within 3D bounding box using numpy logical_and or where?

Tags: python, numpy

I have a large list of points `(x, y, z)`.

```
points = np.random.rand(999).reshape(333, 3)
```

I also have two points representing the minimum and maximum corners of a 3D bounding box representing points of interest

```
min_point = np.random.rand(3)
min_x, min_y, min_z = min_point[0], min_point[1], min_point[2]

max_point = np.random.rand(3)
max_x, max_y, max_z = max_point[0], max_point[1], max_point[2]
```

I am trying to select indices in `points` which lie within this bounding box but am having issues. I originally attempted using `np.where`

```
poi_inds = np.where(
    points[:, 0] > min_x and points[:, 0] < max_x and
    points[:, 1] > min_y and points[:, 1] < max_y and
    points[:, 2] > min_z and points[:, 2] < max_z
)
```

Though this results in

```
ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous.
```

because `and`'ing the results of each comparison is ambiguous (from my understand `numpy` can't decide to do element-wise or entire array `and`).

I found an SO answer which provides [a solution in the 2D case](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42352622/finding-points-within-a-bounding-box-with-numpy) and I've attempted [to expand it](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20528566/2985796) to the 3D case

```
poi_inds = np.all(np.logical_and.reduce((
    points[:, 0] > min_x, points[:, 0] < max_x,
    points[:, 1] > min_y, points[:, 1] < max_y,
    points[:, 2] > min_z, points[:, 2] < max_z)))
```

Though this seems to always result in no points being selected (`poid_inds = (False)`, if I remove the `np.all` I find all indices are `False`) even after running the SSCCE below multiple times.

```
import numpy as np

points = np.random.rand(999).reshape(333, 3)

rand_pt0 = np.random.rand(3)
rand_pt1 = np.random.rand(3)
# Ensure the minimum point is always less than the maximum
min_point = np.array([
    rand_pt0[0] if rand_pt0[0] < rand_pt1[0] else rand_pt1[0],
    rand_pt0[1] if rand_pt0[1] < rand_pt1[1] else rand_pt1[1],
    rand_pt0[2] if rand_pt0[2] < rand_pt1[2] else rand_pt1[2],
])
max_point = np.array([
    rand_pt1[0] if rand_pt0[0] < rand_pt1[0] else rand_pt0[0],
    rand_pt1[1] if rand_pt0[1] < rand_pt1[1] else rand_pt0[1],
    rand_pt1[2] if rand_pt0[2] < rand_pt1[2] else rand_pt0[2],
])

min_x, min_y, min_z = min_point[0], min_point[1], min_point[2]
max_x, max_y, max_z = max_point[0], max_point[1], max_point[2]

# poi_inds = np.where(
#     points[:, 0] > min_x and points[:, 0] < max_x and
#     points[:, 1] > min_y and points[:, 1] < max_y and
#     points[:, 2] > min_z and points[:, 2] < max_z
# )

poi_inds = np.logical_and.reduce((
    points[:, 0] > min_x, points[:, 0] < max_x,
    points[:, 1] > min_y, points[:, 1] < max_y,
    points[:, 2] > min_z, points[:, 2] < max_z))
```

**What is the proper use of `np.where` or `np.logical_and` in this case to locate the points within the described bounding box?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `points` is a Numpy array you can use `&` instead of `np.logical_and` to write this as:

```py
  mask_x = (points[:, 0] >= min_x) & (points[:, 0] <= max_x)
  mask_y = (points[:, 1] >= min_y) & (points[:, 1] <= max_y)
  mask_z = (points[:, 2] >= min_z) & (points[:, 2] <= max_z)
  mask = mask_x & mask_y & mask_z
  indices = np.where(mask)
```

Which, from a quick test, seems to be faster than the solution by KDecker.

Answer (score 1):

I have found a compact solution which utilizes `np.where`, `functools.reduce`, and `np.intersect1d`

```
from functools import reduce

poi_inds = reduce(np.intersect1d, (
    np.where(points[:, 0] > min_x),
    np.where(points[:, 0] < max_x),
    np.where(points[:, 1] > min_y),
    np.where(points[:, 1] < max_y),
    np.where(points[:, 2] > min_z),
    np.where(points[:, 2] < max_z)
))
```

On large lists >100M points this is many times faster than iterating through the points "manually".

```
poi_inds = []
for ind, pt in enumerate(points):
    if min_x < pt[0] < max_x and min_y < pt[1] < max_y and min_z < pt[2] < max_z:
        poi_inds.append(ind)
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are comparing an array with an element.

```
points[:, 0] > min_x
```

An array cannot be compared with a single element.
Instead, you need to use a loop.

```
for i in range(333):
    points[i:0] > min_x
```